# Why is my sitecore shared sessions database looking for a version 8.1.0.0 dll?

Tags: session-state

I'm running Sitecore 8.2 Update 4, and I'm trying to turn on shared SQL sessions. I've followed the instructions found [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/session_state/walkthrough_configure_a_shared_session_state_database_using_the_sql_server_provider), and made these changes.

In my web.config file:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="mssql" cookieless="false" timeout="1">
  <providers>
    <add name="mssql"
         type=" Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql"
         connectionStringName="session"
         pollingInterval="2"
         compression="true" 
         sessionType="private"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

In my ConnectionStrings.config file,

```
<add name="session" connectionString="user id=my_Service_Account;password=my_Password;Data Source=my_IP_Address;Database=SitecoreSessions"/>
```

In my Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config file, I've got this change:

```
<tracking>
        <sharedSessionState defaultProvider="mssql">
            <providers>
                <add name="InProc">
                    <patch:delete/>
                </add> 
              <clear/>
              <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider,Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" sessionType="shared"/>
            </providers>
        </sharedSessionState>
    </tracking>
```

Everything seems to work fine on my development sandbox. However, once I deploy my changes to our test server, which has multiple server roles (i.e. CM/CD/Reporting/Processing and Aggregation), I get this error on the CD Server's log:

> 676 15:28:10 WARN  Failed to deserialize Session object. Exception:
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Exceptions.TypeNotAllowedForBindingException
>   Message: Binding for type Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession
>   from assembly Sitecore.Analytics, Version=8.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null is not allowed. Source: Sitecore.Analytics    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Sessions.WhitelistSerializationBinder.BindToType(String
>   assemblyName, String typeName)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Bind(String
>   assemblyString, String typeString)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo
>   assemblyInfo, String name)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String
>   objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA,
>   Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader
>   objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo,
>   SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped
>   record)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Sessions.PushSession.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)

I've noticed that my `Sitecore.Analytics.dll` version is 10.0.3, not 8.1.0.0, as is being requested in the .NET stack trace. I'm not sure why Sitecore is looking for version 8.1 instead of version 8.2 of that DLL. Where can I go to start figuring out how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is your project is upgraded to 8.2 from 8.1? It may be referring to older dll somewhere from the project.

Comment: can you compare dlls from your solution with a clean sitecore solution wich has same release like your project

Comment: @MohitDharmadhikari - Yes, this was upgraded from Sitecore 8.1, but I'm not seeing any references to the older DLLs.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber - I was able to compare, and found that my CD Servers had 2 Sitecore 8.1 files that are not part of the 8.2 release: `Sitecore.Cloud.ContentSearch.dll` and `Sitecore.Cloud.Xdb.dll`. I removed those and that error has gone away now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help you. I will transform my comment into an answer, to be more visible if others has same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remarked on a few updated old assemblies that are not overrideable by the files from update package.

For me looks like you still have some assemblies from old solution.

Please compare assemblies from your solution with a clean Sitecore solution which is using the same release version as your project.